# Jquery : To redirect from one page to another page

Tags: jquery, html

I have two js pages(Source.js and Target.js) at two different location, now all i want to do is when user clicks on dropdown list of source page , it redirects  user to target page and vice-versa. I am providing you the exact coding with all location and everthing, i just want to know how to switch from one page to second page.

Source.js coding

```
var SourceSc = function() {
var that = {};
var _view = null;
var _childPanel = "#content";
var _sourceDlgMgrC = null;
var BEGIN = "BEGIN";
var STARTING = "STARTING";
var END = "END";
var TARGET = "TARGET";  
var _state = BEGIN;
that.create = function(parent, panel) {

    _parent = parent;
    _panel = panel;
    _transition(STARTING);
};
that.destroy = function() {
    _transition(END);
};
that.eventTargetLanguageView = function() {
    _transition(TARGET_LANGUAGE_VIEW);
};
var _transition = function(newState) {
    _state = newState;
    switch(_state) {                
        case STARTING: _enterStarting(); break;
            case TARGET: _enterTargetDlg(); break;
        case END: _enterEnd(); break;
    }
};
var _enterStarting = function() {
    modelMgr.loadInclude('code/app/sc/LoggedIn/sc/Source/c/SourceDlgMgrC.js', function() {
        modelMgr.getHTML('code/app/sc/LoggedIn/sc/Source/Source.html', function(html) {
            _sourceDlgMgrC = SourceDlgMgrC();
            _sourceDlgMgrC.create(_childPanel);
            var req = {};
            var fnSuccess = function(res) {
                _view = SourceV();
                _view.create(that, _panel, html, res);                  
            };              
        });
    });
};  
var _enterTargetDlg = function() 
{
//now what i have to write here, to load target page
};
var _enterEnd = function() {
     //coding of destroy    
};  
return that;};
var SourceV = function() {
var that = {};

var _sc = null;
var _panel = null;

that.create = function(sc, panel, html, res) {
    _sc = sc;
    _panel = panel;
    that.layoutUi(html);
    that.bindEvents();  
};  
that.layoutUi = function(html) {

    $(_panel).html(html);       
};
that.bindEvents = function() {

    $('#viewList').change(_sc.eventTargetLanguageView);
};
that.destroy = function() {
    $(_panel).html('');
    _panel = null;
    _sc = null;
};
return that; };
```

i can post source.html full coding but i guess that'll be use less so i'll post only the dropdown list coding

```
    <select id = "viewList" class="fl width160">
            <option>Source</option>
            <option>Target</option>
        </select>
```

now coding of target page is also exact same but location of Target.js is "code/app/sc/LoggedIn/sc/Target/Target.js"

Comment: What about `location.href = 'yourNewPage';`?

Comment: @mattytommo please be more clear

Comment: To go to another page, can't you just do the code `location.href = 'yourNewPage';`. That will redirect the browser to a page called `yourNewPage`.

Comment: are you talking about coding from jquery ????

Comment: It's standard Javascript code. See here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...(just for example)

```
 codeLoadingMgr.loadInclude( path + '/AdminSc.js', function() {
 _adminSc = AdminSc();
  _adminSc.create(that, path, _childPanel,_selectedAdminTab, _programId); 
   });
```